# __block EXC_BAD_ACCESS :in block call self method?

Tags: ios

In my UIViewContrller have a download block method

```
-(void)test
{
    __block UIViewController *temp = self;
    [[DownloadController sharedDownload] _complete:^{
        [temp testMethod];
    }];
}
```

Now when I exit the ViewContrller the download not complete.
When the download done,my block method error "[temp testMethod]; EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Answer (score 0):

`__block` also means this object is not retained by block. So when you call pop view controller and then try to call `testMethod` you send a message to a deallocated object.

Possible solutions:
- retain view controller until it complete downloading handling (but the string with `__block` is written correctly). This way will work but it seems incorrect.
- use notifications instead of call the method from block directly
- use another object to handle downloading result for example any singleton

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you're using MRC because '__block' in MRC means 'self' will not be retained by block.   When you exit the view controller, 'self' is released; When downloading is complete and the block is called, 'temp' will be a dangling pointer.

If you want to make sure that testMethod should be executed when downloading is finished, you should use:

```
-(void)test
{
    [[DownloadController sharedDownload] _complete:^{ 
        [self testMethod];
    }];
}
```

Otherwise, you could change your file to be ARC, and use the following code:

```
-(void)test
{
    __weak UIViewController *temp = self;
    [[DownloadController sharedDownload] _complete:^{
       [temp testMethod];
    }];
}
```